# Getting data from Aerospike into SQL Server

Tags: aerospike

What are the options for getting data from Aerospike to SQL Server? I assume exporting to a flat file and then importing into SQL Server. Any others?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to go forward with it would be to export the data from Aerospike using [asbackup](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/backup/), and then write a parser to dump the required data into SQL or any place else as per the required format from the backup dump.

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike's [**asbackup**](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/backup/file_format.html)  dumps the data in human readable format. The same can be parsed accordingly and dumped into MySQL.

Comment: The keys aren't human readable since Aerospike stores the RIPEMD-160 hash of the key and not the key itself. For example, in my backup file I can see a line that looks like this: `- M ip_address 24 ga0DMjAxLjkxLjEyMS42Au==`. One possible workaround would be to store the key in its own column if you need to export to a RDBMS.